# MAGENTO 2 How to Get Current page layout

Tags: magento-2.1.7, category-attribute, page-layouts

How do I get current category "`page_layout`" value? e.g "`1 column`" or "`2 column`" and so on. The values from Layout screen shoot bellow.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to achieve the exact same thing. I ended up creating a helper class that injects both `\Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page` and `\Magento\Framework\View\Layout`.

The Page object can retrieve the selected layout using the method named `getConfig()->getPageLayout()`. But this method will return `NULL` if the page layout has not been selected in the admin area. So I ended up adding a custom method that will return the default page layout if no layout has been selected.

### Helper class example

```php
<?php

namespace {VendorName}\{ModuleName}\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class Data extends AbstractHelper
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
     */
    protected $_pageResult;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Layout
     */
    protected $_layout;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Layout $layout,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page $pageResult)
    {
        $this->_pageResult = $pageResult;
        $this->_layout = $layout;

        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Will return the currect page layout.
     *
     * @return string The current page layout.
     */
    public function getCurrentPageLayout()
    {
        $currentPageLayout = $this->_pageResult->getConfig()->getPageLayout();

        if (is_null($currentPageLayout))
        {
            return $this->_layout->getUpdate()->getPageLayout();
        }

        return $currentPageLayout;
    }
}
```

### Template file usage

```php
<?php

$data = $this->helper('{VendorName}\{ModuleName}\Helper\Data');

echo '<pre> Page Layout:' , $data->getCurrentPageLayout(), '</pre>';
```

This might not be the best way to achieve this, but with Magento2's lack of documentation for developers, this is the only solution I could find that works in later versions of Magento2. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can inject BuilderInterface to your constructor

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Model\PageLayout\Config\BuilderInterface $pageLayoutBuilder
    ) {
        $this->pageLayoutBuilder = $pageLayoutBuilder;
}

public function getLayouts() {
    $pageLayout = [];
    $pageLayout = $this->pageLayoutBuilder->getPageLayoutsConfig()->toOptionArray();    
    unset($pageLayout[0]);
    return $pageLayout;
}
```

Comment: your code returns null. no matter what column I set to. thanks