# Magento2 : Get Current Page layout

Tags: magento2, page-layouts

I have Added Custom [page layout](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117997/how-to-create-custom-layout-page-in-custom-theme?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) in my store.
And set `Test Category Page`
But when I try to [get](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/202824/magento-2-how-to-get-current-page-layout?rq=1&utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) my phtml file in category page

```
$request = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http');
$layout = $request->getFullActionName();
```

It's `catalog_category_view`. I want there `Test Category Page` id which was I had set in Admin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Page layout and handler are two different elements at Magento layout.**

> Page layout is 1column,2 columns-left,2 columns-right,cutome_home.

Where

> handler is
> `cms_index_index.xml`,catalog_product_view,`default`,catalog_category_view etc

**In Magento2, a page layout element can be managed using Layout handler .**

At Magento, a unique handler created basically on Full Action Name every page.

**If you trying at .phtml file**

then use

> $block->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getPageLayout()

**At BLock class use**

> $this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getPageLayout()

Comment: So, How can I get Page layout 'cutome_home' ID?

Comment: I want to put there condition if it is 'Test Category Page' layout

Comment: This only shows 1column even though I manually changed the page layout to a custom page layout which inherits from 1column