# How to Get Layout Name in which is block is placed

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks

I have My block

```
 <block class="Vendor\ModuleName\Block\Frontend\Linked" name="catalog.product.linked" template="Vendor_ModuleName::slide.phtml" />
```

in this file

> app\code\Vendor\ModuleName\view\layout\catalog_product_view.xml

all i need to do is i want `catalog_product_view` name in my `slide.phtml` file

Comment: What's the purpose of that? Cause I don't think you can get that info in a phtml file, inside application flow

Comment: i am placing my same block in two diffrent xml layout files... after that i just wanna check from which layout block is call

Comment: did you check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/228021/magento2-get-current-page-layout?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: i have tried this earlier what i got is `1column`

Comment: I guess that you want to try to get the handle  file name from where `slide.phtml`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this from phtml

```
$full_action_name = $this->getRequest()->getFullActionName();
```

It will return `catalog_product_view`, most of the time full action name is equal to layout name.

Example: module-catalog/etc/frontend/routes.xml

```
<route id="catalog" frontName="catalog">
   <module name="Magento_Catalog" />
</route>
```

The layout area path can be frontend or adminhtml which define where the layout will be applied.There is a special layout file name default.xml which will be applied for all the page in it’s area. Otherwhile, the layout file will have name as format:

```
 {router_id}_{controller_name}_{action_name}.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use other solution - input type of block (or place where block is used) by `<action method="setLinkType">...</action>`

Advantages of this solution are the name of the block name.

You can put in your layout configuration (app\code\Vendor\ModuleName\view\layout\catalog_product_view.xml):

```
<block class="Vendor\ModuleName\Block\Frontend\Linked" name="catalog.product.linked" template="Vendor_ModuleName::slide.phtml">
    <action method="setLinkType">
        <argument name="link_type" xsi:type="string">place_one</argument>
    </action>
</block>
```

Than you will get link type with `$this->getLinkType()` (in Vendor\ModuleName\Block\Frontend\Linked class) or `$block->getLinkType()` (in slide.phtml file)

For example:

```
if ($block->getLinkType() == 'place_two') {
    $do = 'something';
}
```